# How to access Power BI Report Server REST API

Tags: .net-core, powerbi, rest, power-bi-report-server

Good Day!

I am creating a sample POC in which i want to access Reports which are build in Power BI Reporting Server. I am creating this application using dotnet core.
I believe that there are rest apis to access these reports. How can i access these REST Apis or do i need to register an app for this and get the client id and client secret key?

Early response is well appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Got this after searching in internet for 2 days. Had to create an app and then token generation which was not at all necessary. Below is the simple link for accessing the power BI reporting APIs:

[SSRS Swagger HUB](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0#/Reports/GetReport)